# Force ecs-agent to pull image while ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR is set to prefer-cached

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I am migrating a set of high-frequency scheduled tasks from Fargate to ECS within EC2 due to the overhead of always pulling images. I see that setting `ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR` to `prefer-cached` will cause the ECS agent to avoid pulling an image that has been previously cached, but this won't work in our setup, which deploys new images overwriting the latest tag.

Is there any way to force the ECS agent to pull the image again after the image has been updated while retaining the `prefer-cached` behavior after that? If not, any suggestions to work around this issue are appreciated.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to make this work like you want unless you start using immutable image tags (new tags on every push). Otherwise, how would it possibly know that the cached version is stale?

Comment: @MarkB Although not recommended to rely on the latest tag, it is unfortunately not uncommon. I can think of a couple of ways to achieve it, so I was wondering if folks at AWS had already enabled it and somehow I missed it from the docs. It seems not.

Comment: I know it's not uncommon, but it doesn't work well with image caching. If you can think of ways that a server would know it's latest image wasn't actually the latest, then why don't you include those ideas here.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be currently no way to achieve this with the ECS agent. In short, it offers only two options: use the local cache or always pull.

I guess going around the ECS agent and clearing the cache directly would work in some cases (e.g. triggering an SSM command on deployments or polling the current tag digest from within the container instances), but, arguably, it would probably be better to just adopt tag immutability.